# What is the diminishing return formula for magic find?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 2, magic find had a fairly well known formula, with no diminishing returns for magic items, and then different curves for rare, set, and unique items (with unique-find diminishing the fastest).

After deciding on the base item type to drop, D2 would roll a chance for it to drop as unique based on the monster, your magic find, and the diminishing return formula, if that failed, it would roll again to see if it dropped as a set item, then again for rare, and finally for magic, dropping a non-magical item only if all of those checks failed.

Does Diablo 3 drop items and use diminishing returns in the same way? If so, is the formula the same, or was it tweaked?

Comment: I don't think there is? The chance is the combined/cumulative stats from your equipment I am pretty sure...

Comment: I checked around the Net, and there doesn't seem to be any concensus. Blizzard hasn't released any info on it yet, though they might include info about it in the game guide later.

Comment: @JamesJiao It's quite possible we'll have to wait for a while to learn the answer, but I thought it'd still be worthwhile to put the  question out there. Unless they botched it like in early Diablo 2, it's almost certain there is some diminishing return formula, otherwise you can get things like more uniques/sets than rares dropping. (In early Diablo 2, you had to hit very exact percentages of magic find to get the best drops, and you could actually get it so nothing but rares or better dropped, if I remember correctly...but it seems unlikely they'd make that mistake again.)

Comment: The following tweet might be of interest: "*Hey Bash can you tell us if there will be Diminishing Return in magic find and if yes how is gonna work with Nephalem Valor?* –hungrak

*Well I don’t think it’s a linear scale, if that’s what you mean. We might share what it is on our game guide sometime after launch.* –Bashiok" found it [here](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/bashiok-on-nephalem-valor-magic-find)

Answer (score 3):

I have personally seen the stats showing diminishing returns.. at about 40% each point you put on shows up less points when you look at your stats.  at 50% I put on a 7% item and only got 2%  I hope this helps..

Comment: Were you in a multiplayer game at the time? I just got around to testing this, and I'm not seeing diminishing return on the character sheet as I add magic find past 40%

Answer (score 2):

Tested in solo(Private game):
Current set I was wearing had 21% magic find.

Added a 10% belt.

31%MF

Switched pants from 0% to 12%

43%MF

Switched a 21% hat to a 25% hat.

47%MF

The percentage shown in details does not reflect this theory.

Answer (score 2):

I have a barb in Act 2 inferno and I have been following the game since 2008...

> **BASHIOK Q/A:**
>
> "QUESTION ASKER: Is Magic Find using diminishing returns in the same way as
>   in Diablo II, where Magic Find stat affected in a different way the
>   chance for blue, yellow and gold drops (actual bonus of MF was
>   diminished for rarest items)?
>   **BASHIOK: No, it’s a literal (and lateral) improvement across the board. We may tweak it but that’s the way it is right now.**"

It doesn't include diminishing returns at the moment according to Bash. This was pretty much confirmed in a tweet Bashiok posted a couple of days ago.

Your welcome question asker.

Comment: Interesting. Can anyone find the original source of this? I can find gaming sites that repost it, but I can't find a definitive date of Bashiok's answer, and the articles I'm finding were published just days after [Bashiok's tweet](https://twitter.com/Bashiok/statuses/184386151774302210) to the contrary. Since the articles seem to be "collected Q&A" from various sources, I'm not sure the tweet that says "I think there are diminishing returns" came before this Q&A.